# C# mailer - 550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name

Tags: c#, smtp

I know there are various thread out there related to this problem but i was unable to take any of the responses on those thread and make it work on my server.

So let try to see if someone can help me out here.
99% of the emails go out properly and few actually return with that error.

My code looks like this

```
        MailMessage mm = new MailMessage(Settings.EmailCustomerService, to, subject, body);
        mm.SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        mm.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;

        MailAddress add = new MailAddress(Settings.EmailCustomerService, "Customer Service");
        mm.From = add;

        try
        {
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient(Settings.EmailSMTP);

            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(Settings.EmailUser, Settings.EmailPwd); 

            System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart threadStart = new System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(SendInThread);
            threadStart.Invoke(new SendInThreadParams
            {
                client = client,
                Message = mm
            });
        }
        finally
        {
            mm = null;
        }
```

Actually the Credentials code was added later but my code was run OK even without it. It just happen that 1% of the email never make it to the recipients and adding those 2 lines for Credentials did not make a difference.

The Settings.EmailUser is just a user on the server where the SMTP runs, but i have NOT attach it to nowhere.

> > I bet that's the problem.

The SMTP Server Relay is set to use 127.0.0.1 and the FQDN is just the name of the machine (something like "Machine1" ...nothing with a domain.com name)

The error I'm getting is this

> Reporting-MTA: dns;Machine1
>   Received-From-MTA: dns;Machine1
>   Arrival-Date: Wed, 30 May 2012 23:08:36 -0700
>   Final-Recipient: rfc822;test@email.net
>   Action: failed
>   Status: 5.5.0
>   Diagnostic-Code: smtp;550 Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1)

Return message emailed back was:

```
   > This is an automatically generated Delivery Status Notification.  
   Delivery to the following recipients failed.  
   test@email.com
```

Thanks in advanced...

Comment: What's the idea with `threadStart`? Hope you dont think that is suppose to start a thread.

Comment: I would not focus on how the email is sent. My current problem is the 550 HELO return I'm getting on 1% of the emails sent.

Comment: @Developer: For those 1%, have you checked how you're sending the HELO command? Try checking via Wireshark. Best guess is the SMTP server does not recognize the parameter.

Comment: @IlianPinzon Never used the tool. I'm watching the videos. what option shall I use on a Win2008 R2 server? And what parameter are u referring to. Am I sending the HELO Command? Not sure, the code i use is above. And why would it work for 99% and not ALWAYS the same 1% ?

Comment: @Developer The `SmtpClient` instance will send the HELO command with a domain parameter to your mail server. This is required to start a mail transaction. This is done automatically for you. Wireshark allows you to see the actual SMTP packets and confirm that it is using the correct domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the message/delivery-status attachment, the DSN will usually have the returned message. For this sort of issue you should post the headers of the returned message and the DSN as well.

It looks to me like your server has accepted the message, but has an error transmitting it onwards. If your server had rejected it, your code would have thrown an exception. So your server Machine1 accepted it, attempted to transmit it to email.net, but email.net rejected it. Machine1 then generated a DSN (delivery status notification, in your case an NDR = Non-Delivery Report).

In other words it is a configuration error with the email server not a code problem. Almost certainly the issue is that the email server is not set up with an FQDN as you stated.

As a configuration problem, it belongs on ServerFault.

Comment: From what i see, the current FQDN is set on the SMTP Virtual Server (running on IIS6 Manager) when I select on Properties, Delivery, Advanced ..and there i have the "Machine1" value. See edited question

If I click on Check DNS button, the message says that it's valid. That setting was already in place.

Comment: I did some research ...trying to find out the FQDN of the server and somewhere i read that it's the combination of the HOST NAME and the PRIMARY DNS SUFFIX. Host Name is "Machine1" but the DNS Suffix is ..."" (empty). Is that the problem ?

Comment: FQDN means "Fully Qualified Domain Name". Emphasis on FULLY. "Machine1" is "unqualified" because it lacks a domain. You should put your email domain in that spot not "Machine1".

Comment: Yep ..you were right. I added a "domain.com" on the PRIMARY DNS SUFFIX and now the 1% does receive those emails. Thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

Based on BEN answer I realized that I was missing the PRIMARY DND SUFFIX.

Mainly in order to find out your FQDN, you need to simply:
1) Open a Command Prompt 
2) Type "ipconfig /all"

Read your HOST NAME + PRIMARY DNS SUFFIX.

My DNS SUFFIX was emtpy so i went and added using this link
http://www.simpledns.com/kb.aspx?kbid=1227

And then rebooted the machine.

Now the code works like a charm.
Thanks BEN !!!

Comment: Can you please give an example of DNS suffix? For example Computer Name is VMI1234, MX=mail.somedomain.com Thanks