# Mailbox Unavailable in c#

Tags: c#

I am attempting to email myself through my program, using this method:

```
MailMessage email = new MailMessage("IT_REQUEST@creandsel.com.au", "ben.hall@creandsel.com.au");
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = 25;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Host = "hp132.hostpapa.com";
email.Subject = "New IT Request";
email.Body = Model.Description;

client.Send(email); // Error catches here
```

However I am getting the error message:

> Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: Access denied - Invalid HELO name (See RFC2821 4.1.1.1)

I have tried alternate hosts (creandsel.com.au), to the same effect. I believe it may be because I am sending this from an internal network to a third party email provider.

Also, not sure if this matters, but the sender (IT_REQUEST@creandsel.com.au) does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that SMTP is [enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949283/getting-a-asp-error-mailbox-unavailable-the-server-response-was-access-denied-server-response-was-access-denied) for your enviroment. If it is enabled, you need to pass SMTP credentials (username/password pair) because is not authenticating successfully with your SMTP server.

```
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
client.Port = 25;
client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
// explicitly declare that you will be providing the credentials:
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password");
client.Host = "hp132.hostpapa.com";
email.Subject = "New IT Request";
email.Body = Model.Description;
```

Comment: Can I clarify what `NetworkCredential` is referring to? is it the user information, the hosting information, or the internal network information?

Comment: @Ben Its the username/password that authenticates your `smtp` server. You need to ask your infra guys what they use for that. If your company is using Microsoft Exchange, it is likely your Win login, in which case you can just use `.UseDefaultCredentials = true` instead. Ironic that `DefaultCredentials` aren't the default.