# Error on sending email when using other mail server expect that gmail

Tags: c#, email, exception, smtp, gmail

*I'm trying to send email from Mail address(hassan@creativesolutionzone.com), but its not sending an unhandled Exception:*

**System.net.mail.smtp exception: Mailbox unavailable. the server response was access denied - Invalid HELO name(see RFC2821 4.1.1.1)**

> Here is the code..

```
private void sendMail() 
{
       login = new NetworkCredential(txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text);
       client = new SmtpClient(txtSMTP.Text);
       client.Port = Convert.ToInt32(txtport.Text);
       client.EnableSsl = chkSSL.Checked;
       client.Credentials = login;
       msg = new MailMessage { From = new MailAddress(txtUsername.Text + txtSMTP.Text.Replace("mail.", "@"), "Creative Solution Zone", Encoding.UTF8) };
       msg.To.Add(txtTO.Text);
       if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtCC.Text))
           msg.To.Add(new MailAddress(txtCC.Text));
       msg.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
       msg.Body = txtMessege.Text;
       msg.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;
       msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
       msg.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
       msg.DeliveryNotificationOptions = DeliveryNotificationOptions.OnFailure;
       client.SendCompleted += new SendCompletedEventHandler(SendCompleteCallBack);
       string userState = "Sending...";
       client.SendAsync(msg, userState);
}


private static void SendCompleteCallBack(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Cancelled)
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0} Send Cancelled ", e.UserState), "Messgae", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    if (e.Error != null)
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("{0}", e.Error), "Messgae", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Your Message Has Been Successfully Sent", "Messgae", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Can Anyone Help me to resolve this?

> Note: When I tried to send mail from my Gmail account, the code is
>   working perfectly but when i change my mail its not working

Comment: For those wondering: [RFC2821 4.1.1.1](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2821#section-4.1.1.1)

Comment: Is the result of `txtUsername.Text + txtSMTP.Text.Replace("mail.", "@")` a valid e-mail address?

Comment: yeah its a valid email..

Comment: Found related issues regarding "invalid HELO name": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10828555/c-sharp-mailer-550-access-denied-invalid-helo-name & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24949283/getting-a-asp-error-mailbox-unavailable-the-server-response-was-access-denied.

Comment: Hi Tetsuya Yamamoto..!!
I've also tried this but for me its not working..

Comment: I guess this is a complex issue with a some misconfiguration on the server. It would be nice to see its logs for this connection.

Comment: is there any other way to send email?